# My Fundamental Misunderstanding of Google Compute Engine Instance

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, remote-desktop

So my goal is to be able to run some programs/applications on remote computer (windows), all day long. So I created a Google Compute Engine VM Instance, win server 2008 R2 (desktop), with 1 CPU and no GPU.

But these programs need a windows os with 32-bit color depth (the current setting on the VM is 16-bit) and windows 2008 does not allow me to change graphics settings via remote desktop connection. So I tried teamviewer to get around this, but the VM instance doesn't seem to even be graphically active unless RDP is used (the screen appears black in teamviewer)? Teamviewer says the vm is a 'probably minimized remote desktop session'. This is worrying as I need the graphics of the vm-instance to be always up and running like a normal computer, not just activated when RDP is used. So it seems like I'm misunderstanding something here.  Basically, teamviewer needs to work at least. Is there a way to do this?